# How do I make the closest four points on a graph glow?

Tags: javascript, flot

As my cursor moves, I grab the two closest points IF it is not already on a plotted point.

I want to be able to make these two closest points light up (i.e. change colour to something orange or something), and then go back to normal once the cursor leaves the scope of the graph. How do I go about implementing this?

```
placeholder.bind("plothover",  function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        local_x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2);
        local_y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);                 
        if (!updateLegendTimeout){
        updateLegendTimeout = setTimeout(updateLegend(local_x,local_y), 1000);
        updateLegendTimeout = null;
        }
    }
    else{
         var closest_points_container = interpolate(plot,pos.x,pos.y);                              

         //Code to make points glow goes here, they are contained in closest_points[0]                   
           and closest_points[1].
    }
```

Comment: dunno how you are drawing your points. if I was starting from scratch I would use SVG's and d3.js; and I would add and remove a class `proximityHilight` on mousemove, and style the svg points with css on those classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot provides highlight and unhighlight methods on the plot object, as described in the [Plot Methods](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods) section of the docs.  Unfortunately that has the restriction that only one point may be highlighted at a time.  That is baked-in; you can't change it without altering the source.

The work-around I would use is to add a second series showing only points, no lines, and set the point style to appear as a highlight, i.e. with translucency.  This highlight series will start out empty; then when you want to highlight a point on your main series you can copy it to the highlight series and redraw.